# Derivatives of vectors

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector

I have an issue with derivatives of vectors

```
$Assumptions :=  v ∈ Vectors[3, Reals] (*Assuming v is a 3d vector*)

D[Norm[v]^2, v.{0, 0, 1}] (*differentiate with respect to third component*)
```

Output: `0`

But isn't this supposed to be:
$\frac{\partial (v_1^2+v_2^2+v_3^2)}{\partial v_3}=2v_3$

Comment: If my answer below answered your question, please accept it so that we can get this question off the unanswered list and so that I can get those meaningless internet points that I so crave!

Comment: @march

Ah! Yep here are your well-deserved points :) Thanks a lot for the help! I simply forgot to click ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how you should probably do this:

```
vec = Array[v, 3]
D[vec.vec, vec.{0, 0, 1}]
(* {v[1], v[2], v[3]} *)
(* 2 v[3] *)
```

I'll just make a couple of points about `D`.

- It doesn't behave well when given functions like `Abs` and `Norm`:

  ```
  D[Norm[{a, b, c}]^2, a]
  (* 2 Abs[a] Abs'[a] *)
  ```

  Instead, you should typically use more explicit forms of vector norms, which is why I used

  ```
  vec.vec
  (* v[1]^2 + v[2]^2 + v[3]^2 *)
  ```
- I would guess that `Vectors` is mainly useful for doing symbolic tensor math, as shown in the documentation. It's not for what you're trying to do with it.
- Meditate on the result of the following evaluation; it will show you why your result was zero and how `D` interprets its arguments.

  ```
  Clear[v]
  D[v.{0, 0, 1}, v.{0, 0, 1}]
  ```

Comment: I upvoted this even though your rep counter was just at `4444`, and now I messed up that nice number. Sorry for that, I guess.

Comment: @Jens I wish I could have stayed there forever. $4444 = 66^2 + 88$; $4444 = 4\times1111$ with $1+1+1+1 = 4$.

Comment: You are correct that `Vectors` is meant for symbolic tensor manipulations and simplifications.